# "List index out of range" despite having a correct line number

Tags: python

I wanted to refrain from posting stupid questions here for as long as I could but I'm not quite sure how to fix this one by myself. I'm trying to read a specific line in a file (line number doesn't change at all) yet I get the error. I am able to print every single line in the file by iterating through it but reading the particular line I need by itself (or any except line 0) throws out the error, although it was working in previous versions (recent change just shuffled the line I needed downwards by 1, I adjusted the line numbers as needed).

The error occurs in this area of the function:

```
with open("wallet.txt","r") as file:
    rawcurrency = file.readlines()[0]
    linesplit = rawcurrency.split(": ")
    currency = linesplit[1]
    rawbalance = file.readlines()[3]
    linesplit = rawbalance.split(": ")
    global balance
    balance = linesplit[1]
```

This line throws the error:

`rawbalance = file.readlines()[3]`

This is how the file I'm reading from looks:

```
Currency used: £
Creation Date: 20/05/2020 19:28:31
Starting Wallet Amount = 500.0
Balance: 500.0
```

I'm sorry in advance if the solution is quite easy.

Comment: Please add the full error message. It tells you (and us) precisely where the error is.

Comment: add the line `file.seek(0)` before the line throwing the error. [Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28873349/python-readlines-not-returning-anything).

Comment: Incidentally, you read the file twice with `file.readlines()` without reopening it. The second time you attempt to read it, you are already at the end of the file.

Comment: file.seek(0) did the job. Thank you jfaccioni! Never knew about that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As DYZ pointed out, you readlines twice. Any way, an easier and more direct solution:

```py
import linecache
...
raw_currency = linecache.getline("wallet.txt", 1)  # Get line 1
raw_balance =  linecache.getline("wallet.txt", 4)  # Get line 4
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the function 
`readlines()` 
reads the entire file and returns a list of the lines in the file.
The first call you make to it,

`file.readlines()[0]`

works for you since it reads the entire file and you access the first index of the list, which is incidentally the line you actually needed.
The second call you make to it,

`file.readlines()[3]`

throws an exception since it reads the entire file **from the location it reached in the previous call** which is the end of the file, meaning it returns an empty list since there are no more lines to read. You then try to access the third index in the list, which doesn't exist, hence the exception.